# PyGame, make the tank gun follow your cursor, also good collision implementation practices

Tags: python, pygame

I'm completely new in pygame and I'm making trying to make a platformer game. I'm also planning to add multiplayer capability in it using sockets. The players are like tanks that can jump and you can move your mouse around to aim the tank's gun in your cursor's direction and shoot when you click.

What I did was I drew a rect, which is the body of the tank, and a line from the center of the rect to the cursor's position, which should be the gun of the tank. Now, the line that was drawn isn't fixed, if i move my mouse away from the tank the line's length will follow the mouse cursor. This is how it looks like:
[image]

I have no idea how to make it a fixed length, I made some kind of math illustration of the problem that might help:
[image]
Where A is the center of the tank, B is the position of the mouse, and R is the length of the gun of the tank, and C is the end point of the gun of the tank. The goal is to get C given A, B, and r, while also taking into account that the distance of A and B can be lower than the radius (because the mouse can go wherever it wants). Although im not sure if the illustration is correct, because it's possible that the mouse might enter the circle and honestly im confused beyond that..

Also one last thing, is there a best way for implementing collision? Because my solution is to just save the coordinates of each platform and and just do if statements like in this way:

if playerY > platform1Y: stop falling

if playerX > platform2X: stop moving left

if playerY < platform3Y: stop moving up

if playerX < platform4Y: stop moving right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to compute the direction vector from *A* to *B*. Compute the unique vector (vector with length 1) and scale it to the radius *r*. Add the vector to the point *A*. The result is the point *C*.
In pygame this computation is very simple. Use [`pygame.math.Vector2`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2) and the operation `scale_to_length()` to get the vector (*V*) form *A* to *C*. Finally add *V* to *C*:

```py
def point_on_circle(ax, ay, bx, by, radius):
    if ax == bx and ay == by:
        return ax, ay

    A = pygame.math.Vector2(ax, ay)
    B = pygame.math.Vector2(bx, by)

    V = B - A
    V.scale_to_length(radius)

    C = A + V
    return C.x, C.y
```

---

You have pass the center of the object to the arguments (`ax, ay`). You can use [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) to compute the center of the rectangle. For instance:

```py
player_rect = pygame.Rect(playerX, playerY, playerWidth, playerHeight)
ax, ay = player_rect.center
```

Comment: it works perfectly but i have a question because it seems like it's following exactly the tail of the cursor, i was expecting it to follow from the where the cursor points, im not sure maybe that's just exactly where the coordinates are located in the mouse?

Comment: [Here's what it looks like](https://snipboard.io/LkvWKx.jpg)

Comment: @user639467 It seems that (ax, ay) is the top left of the object rather than the center. You have to pass the center of the green rectangle to the arguments (ax, ay). I'Ve e extended the answer.

Comment: nvm man it's actually some previous formula for finding C i tried that i forgot to remove lol, anyways thank you again!